# Hibernate OneToOne bidirectional foreign key on insert

Tags: oracle, hibernate, foreign-keys

I'm having a problem when calling insert using hibernate. The foreign key is not being passed down to the child on the `OneToOne` mappings, but it's working fine for the `OneToMany` mappings.

**School.java**

```
private long schoolId;
private set<Student> students;
private Principal principal;

@Id
@Column(name = "SCHOOL_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
public long getSchoolId() {
    return schoolId;
}
public void setSchoolId( long schoolId ) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "school")
public set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}
public void setStudents( set<Student> students ) {
    this.students = students;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "school")
public Principal getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
}
public void setPrincipal( Principal principal ) {
    this.principal = principal;
}
```

**Student.java**

```
private long studentId;
private School school;
other data....

@Id
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
public long getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}
public void setStudentId( long studentId ) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID", nullable = false)
public School getSchool() {
    return school;
}
public void setSchool( School school ) {
    this.school = school;
}
```

**Principal.java**

```
private long principalId;
private School school;
//other data....

@Id
@Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
public long getPrincipalId() {
    return principalId;
}
public void setPrincipalId( long principalId ) {
    this.principalId = principalId;
}

@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID", nullable = false)
public School getSchool() {
    return school;
}
public void setSchool( School school ) {
    this.school = school;
}
```

With this example, when i try to save an School object, the hibernate would call insert on School, then Students, then Principal. When it calls insert on all the students, hibernate calls

```
insert into STUDENT ( SCHOOL_ID, STUDENT_ID ) values (?, ?)
```

which is correct. But when it tries to call insert on the principal, hibernate calls

```
insert into PRINCIPAL ( PRINCIPAL_ID) values (?)
```

which causes

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PRINCIPAL"."SCHOOL_ID")

since the foreign key for the School object is not being inserted. I don't understand why it inserts the foreign key for the `OneToMany` tables, but not the `OneToOne` tables. Does anyone know how to fix this? these tables are bi-directional.

Also, I'm have a controller that takes in the School object and save to DB. The object looks like this

```
{
    "name" : "data",
    "students" : [ {"name", "data"}],
    "principal" : {"name", "data"}
}
```

when I receive this school object, do I have to loop through the child and set the parent to school? because in this example it's only 2 levels, but I would need to build 4-5 levels, and would not like to loop all the way down to set each of the parents. I don't have to use bi-directional, if uni-directional work, I would do that.

Comment: `School` <-> `Principal` is bidirectional in the relational model also in your example. So how can foreign keys on both sides be not-nullable without using deferred constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Add mappedBy to the OneToOne annotation in Principal class:

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="principal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: thanks for the respond, I tried that and it didn't work. I updated the question to include this.